# How can I check whether an HTML attribute is true or false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `div` block and I'm wondering how can I check each `col-md-4` div which has a nested div of `entry-footer`, checking the `template-include="false"` if it's true or false.

I have to write this in JavaScript/jQuery, however, I'm still very new to web programming and JavaScript.

```html
<div id="divtemp-sc" class="container-fluid tab-pane active tab-padding" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="divtemp-sc">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 1</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 1</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 2</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 2</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="true">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 3</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 3</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [Attribute Equals Selector `[name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to do this work.

```js
$(".col-md-4 .entry-footer [template-include='true']").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divtemp-sc" class="container-fluid tab-pane active tab-padding" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="divtemp-sc">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 1</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 1</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 2</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 2</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="true">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 3</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 3</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I access the other divs and get the texts in them? Like i found the 2nd one as true. I want to access the `entry-header` and `entry-body`

Comment: @Hexxed If you mean get text of `entry-header` that has sibling with `template-include=true` use http://jsfiddle.net/fjh7gnqL/

Answer (score 1):

`each` loops through elements with the same attribute, in the case the class `col-sm-4`.

`find` looks for element with certain attribute within the elements scope.

```js
$('.col-md-4').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.entry-footer-include-btn').attr('template-include') == 'true')
    console.log('true');
  else
    console.log('false');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divtemp-sc" class="container-fluid tab-pane active tab-padding" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="divtemp-sc">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 1</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 1</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 2</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 2</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="true">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="popup-temp-entry">
      <div class="entry-header">Title 3</div>
      <div class="entry-body">Description 3</div>
      <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery here. If you can be sure that there is going to be a `template-include` in place, it can be as simple as the following snippet.

I added comments to explain what I'm doing.

```js
document
  // find all elements that have some sort of templace-include set.
  .querySelectorAll('.entry-footer [template-include]')
  .forEach((elm) => {
    const value = elm.getAttribute('template-include') === 'true'; // check if it's true
    const header = elm
      .closest( '.popup-temp-entry' ) // find closest parent
      .querySelector( '.entry-header' ); // find the header
    console.log(`${ header.innerText } is ${ value }`);
    
    if ( value ) {
      header.style.color = 'green';
      header.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="popup-temp-entry">
  <div class="entry-header">Text 1</div>
  <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
</div>
<div class="popup-temp-entry">
  <div class="entry-header">Text 2</div>
  <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="true">Include</a></div>
</div>
<div class="popup-temp-entry">
  <div class="entry-header">Text 3</div>
  <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's not needed to use jQuery. The following snippet can also be used without jQuery. The same selectors that are used by Mohammed can also be used with JavaScript.

```js
var element = document.body.querySelector(".col-md-4 .entry-footer [template-include='true']");
element.style.color = "red"
console.log("Content is "  + element.textContent)
```

```html
<div id="divtemp-sc" class="container-fluid tab-pane active tab-padding" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="divtemp-sc">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="popup-temp-entry">
            <div class="entry-header">Title 1</div>
            <div class="entry-body">Description 1</div>
            <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="popup-temp-entry">
            <div class="entry-header">Title 2</div>
            <div class="entry-body">Description 2</div>
            <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="true">Is true</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="popup-temp-entry">
            <div class="entry-header">Title 3</div>
            <div class="entry-body">Description 3</div>
            <div class="entry-footer"><a href="#" class="entry-footer-include-btn" template-include="false">Include</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```