# Refactoring JavaScript code to jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've modified this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187545/4466640) and got it working. However, I want to improve it by translating this JQuery code for uniformity since I'm working with a team. Can I somehow convert the code to JQuery?

**Javascript Code**

```
var o = document.querySelector("#divTwo");
var gg = o.querySelector('#tempType [aria-selected="true"]').innerText;
o.querySelectorAll('[templateList="me"] .entry-footer [template-include = "true"]').forEach( (elm) => {
    var a = elm.closest( '.popup-temp-entry' ).querySelector( '.entry-header' ).innerText;
    var b = elm.closest( '.popup-temp-entry' ).querySelector( '.entry-body' ).innerText;
    console.log(a +' - '+ b + ' - ' + gg);
});
```

Comment: you dont need to convert this in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to convert that JavaScript to jQuery, just do this:

```
var o = $("#divTwo);
var gg = o.filter("#tempType [aria-selected='true']").text();
o.filter("[templateList='me'] .entry-footer [template-include = 'true']").each((elm) => {
    var a = elm.next(".popup-temp-entry").filter(".entry-header").val();
    var b = elm.next(".popup-temp-entry").filter(".entry-body").val();
    console.log(`${a} - ${b} - gg`);
})
```

Just make sure you have included jQuery correctly:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also try this one.

```
var o = $("#divTwo"),
    gg = o.find("#tempType [aria-selected='true']").text()

o.find("[templateList='me'] .entry-footer [template-include='true']").forEach( (elm) => {
  var foo = elm.closest( '.popup-temp-entry' ),
      a = foo.find(".entry-header").text(),
      b = foo.find("entry-body").text()
  console.log(gg, a, b)
})
```